# How to use a gem in logstash pipeline ruby filter

Tags: ruby, logstash

I have a ruby file with dependency modules and this file is being called in a logstash pipeline.
ie ...

```
filter{

  ruby {
    path  => "/path/to/script.rb"
  }

}
```

I get an error that they can't be found when the script is called through the logstash pipeline in the pod where its running.

How or where do I install these?
Can I run
"gem install my-gem"
somewhere in the pipeline or how would you go about completing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to install a gem (yet at least). However there might be a few options:

1. You can add a Gem to `/usr/share/logstash/Gemfile` and then use them gem in your script as usual. Apparently this can be bit flaky since an update to logstash might need a re-install of the gem.
2. Write a custom plugin, but that can be an overkill for what you might want.
3. As the author of the ticket linked below said, you can: add you Gem to logstash's Gemfile at `/usr/share/logstash/Gemfile`, force a gem update by running `/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin update logstash-filter-grok` and then use it in your Ruby filter. Ref to the ticket below for more details.

NOTE:
This answer uses information referenced in this ticket here:

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/7016

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think the link you posted is by mistake linking back to this question

Comment: @4cody yes my bad. fixed.