# '--enable-local-plugin-development' error- What is the fix for production

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems, logstash

I have a ruby script that requires 3rd party gems, I'm using in the filter section of logstash built out with docker.  I'm using the logstash base image and installing the ruby gems in the docker file .
eg

```
FROM .../logstash:7.16.2

RUN /usr/share/logstash/bin/ruby -S gem install *gem*

RUN echo "gem '*gem*'" >> /usr/share/logstash/Gemfil
```

This is the only solution I could find in order to utilize the gems in my ruby script thats being called in the filter of logstash.

From here if I run my image, I will get an error -

```
[Fatal] Logstash-Logstash was unable to start due to an unexpected Gemfile change.
If you are a user this is a bug.
If you are a logstash developer, please try restarting logstash with the '--enable-local-plugin-development' flag set.
```

If I append the noted flag to my run command I am able to run locally.
eg

```
docker run my-image-build --enable-local-plugin-development
```

But this does not work when I deploy to dev/prod.

I will receive the same error ([FATAL]) in the pod logs.

The noted flag is meant for development purposes
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/running-logstash-command-line.html
and I don't know of a way to append the flag to the docker run command in dev/prod if I could use it.

What is the fix for this so I can use the script in dev/prod?

Have I attempted to add the gems in a way that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This was an additional question to get clarity with an issue I was facing -- this issue is resolved by this answer.
[How to use a gem in logstash pipeline ruby filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341179/how-to-use-a-gem-in-logstash-pipeline-ruby-filter)

Specifically the docker file is where I'm installing ruby gems for use in logstash filter ruby script.

I have to add a final line at the end of the docker file after installing gems and adding them to the gemfile..
The docker file looks like this.

```
FROM .../logstash:7.16.2

RUN /usr/share/logstash/bin/ruby -S gem install *gem*

RUN echo "gem '*gem*'" >> /usr/share/logstash/Gemfile

RUN /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash-plugin update logstash-filter-grok
```